# Remove the regional files from a LightSwitch deployment

Tags: deployment, build, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there some way to remove the multitude of region specific files in the LightSwitch \bin directory ? ... *apart from manually*

We only deploy for local, so having the various language/region specific files seems a waste, increasing build and deployment times

Comment: create a batch file which runs in post-build event. you'll probably have to specify which DLLs in the batch file, but it'll only take a few minutes (and only once)

Comment: @jberger Yeah I was sort of coming to that conclusion, but I had my fingers crossed that there was a built-in option in LightSwitch

Comment: we'd be grateful if you published your solution as an answer and accept it as so.